# LibGDX movement distortion

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

Yet another problem I have encountered on my quest to creating a game in Java with the LibGDX framework. The problem occures when i try to move a sprite, texture or texture region it becomes all blurry at edges and it lights up in the direction of movement. I am moving it by simply increasing the draw coordinates in the render method. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're calling render twice before clearing the screen giving a trailing effect.  If I'm right, when your sprite moves faster, you'll see more blurring on the edges.

Could you post a simple example demonstrating your issue?

Comment: The `blurry`-bit sounds like an anti-aliasing thing. This is usually intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your texture filters to linear.

```
texturename.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Comment: I tried vSynch and anti-aliasing and texture.setFilter(...) but nothing seems to work. Can the speed cause this problem?

Comment: I have seen that this problem occurs in many other cases over internet and no one has provided an answer... Does anybody know why this is happening?